# How to use ddd with roslaunch?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, gdb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to debug some segfaults and I was wondering if anyone managed to get ddd / gdb (https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) working with nodes that were launched with roslaunch (and if so, how to do so).

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269332/how-to-use-ddd-with-roslaunch?/) by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2017-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Follow the instructions [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB)

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2017-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0